# How to change font-family for italic in Sublime Text 3

Tags: fonts, sublimetext3

I like the style of text editor of Wes Bos, and I want to make my editor look like his.

I found this [article](https://medium.com/@docodemore/an-alternative-to-operator-mono-font-6e5d040e1c7e), but I can't find anywhere how to set other font only for italic text in SublimeText 3.

Is there any way there to achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line into your user setting:

```
"font_options": ["italic"],
```

Other options you may need for font:

```
"font_face": "Dank Mono",
"font_options": ["italic"],
"font_size": 15,
```